# React and Django REST not fully authenticating?

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I built a app with react, django and used DRF, I have a log in page which when successful passed a token, basically, it logs in fine but just noticed that i have a component which gets data from a particular logged in user and i used "IsAuthenticated" as a decorator, I notice it shows in the API, but not in my frontend, I removed "IsAuthenticated" decorator, and check the network then i noticed it shows: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'follow_user' ... even when im logged in react.

Please help I dont understand what is going on.

This is the Login.js

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
      };
    
      handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
    
      onFinish = values => {
          console.log(values);
        //   values.preventDefault();
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        this.props.login(username, password);
      };

  render() {
    const { error, loading, token } = this.props;
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    if (token) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
        <Layout>
               <Layout>
                    <L
                    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
                        <TabPane tab="Login" key="1">
                            <Content>
                                  <h2>Log in to your account</h2>
                                            <div>
                                                {error && <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>}
                                                    <React.Fragment>
                                                    <Form
                                                        {...layout}
                                                        name="basic"
                                                        initialValues={{ remember: false }}
                                                        onFinish={this.onFinish}
                                                        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
                                                        // onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                                        >
                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                            value={username}
                                                            label="Username"
                                                            name="username"
                                                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}
                                                        >
                                                            <Input />
                                                        </Form.Item>

                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                            value={password}
                                                            label="Password"
                                                            name="password"
                                                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}
                                                        >
                                                            <Input.Password />
                                                        </Form.Item>

                                                        <Form.Item {...tailLayout} name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
                                                            <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                                                        </Form.Item>

                                                        <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                                                            <Button type="primary" 
                                                            loading={loading}
                                                            disabled={loading}
                                                            htmlType="submit">
                                                            Log in
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </Form.Item>
                                                    </Form>
                                                    
                                                </React.Fragment>
                                                
                                        </div>
                                </Content>
                        </TabPane>
                        <TabPane tab="Sign Up" key="2">
                         Content of Tab Pane 2
                        </TabPane>

                    </Tabs>
                    
                </Layout>


                </Layout>
            </Layout>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      loading: state.auth.loading,
      error: state.auth.error,
      token: state.auth.token
    };
  };
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      login: (username, password) => dispatch(authLogin(username, password))
    };
  };
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(LoginForm);
```

Comment: You need `IsAuthneticated` decorator if you want to restrict access to view to only authenticated users. So it is up to you if you want any user access the view or only logged users? I can recommend two articles: [React Token Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/) and [CRUD in Django Rest Framework and React](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/crud-django-rest-framework-react/).